# Beautiful Soup doesn't find first XML tag

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, tags

Question already appeared [Beautiful Soup Can't Find the First Tag (XML)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43444211/beautiful-soup-cant-find-the-first-tag-xml#43444531) but wasn't resolved.

I'm facing the same problem, and I cannot see why this easy task cannot be resolved by a simple `find_all <sentence/> tags` function using Python:

```
for tag in items.find_all('sentence'):
    print(tag)
```

It remains just empty. Any idea why this is occurring?

Comment: what is your xml look like

Comment: Try using `xml.etree` instead.

Comment: @galaxyan my XML appeared in the previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49792703/conditional-xml-parsing-in-python

Comment: I cannot confirm your problem. `items.findAll('sentence')` works for me (returns the `sentence` tag with all its contents). My parser is "lxml". What parser do you use?

Comment: The only currently supported XML parser is lxml-xml (see https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser )so make sure you are using it.